# Пространство имен System.Runtime.Serialization.Json

Tags: c#

Не могу подгрузить пространство имен `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json`. Где можно скачать библиотеку с такой сборкой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.jsonreaderwriterfactory(v=VS.90).aspx) в `System.ServiceModel.Web.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

Добав референс System.Runtime.Serialization.dll этот дллку.